# problem when Java and C++ talk with each other

Tags: java, c++

I have a program in C++ and it writes a binary file on disk. Then I use a Java program to read the number. The problem is the number read is different from the number written.

Say, I  write an integer 4 using c++ and get back 67108864 when use JAVA to read it (using `readint()`). I suspect its due to big or small endian. Do you have any simple solutions to solve this?

Comment: That does look like endian-ness (67108864 = 0x04000000), are the two programs running on different hardware?  It could also be that you're just off by 3 bytes for some reason...

Comment: (Note that C and C++ are more slack about order of evaluation. In particular, if you were using C to read, multiple get operations in a expression are likely to be executer in the opposite order you might naively expect.)

Comment: that's on the same machine... I am curious if there is any libs in Java can solve this.

Comment: note, you should make sure that your c++ codes writes data in a predictable byte order, in case you plan on running it on a different machine on the future.  best way to do that is to use the network byte order helper methods.

Answer (score 3):

Java's `java.nio` buffers let you specify the endianness.

See http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html especially the [`order`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#order%28java.nio.ByteOrder%29) method which lets you specify endianness and the [`getInt`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#getInt%28%29) method which lets you read an int.

To read a file using a `ByteBuffer` do something like:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = new RandomAccessFile(myFile, "r")
    .getChannel.map(MapMode.READ, offset, length);
```

Remember to close it when you're done.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman, will update to a newer version of the docs.

Comment: Thanks!!! I am new to Java, can you give a more specific example? I have a string "file" storing the filename, byte[] bytes = new byte[10];
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);

Comment: Thanks!!! I am new to Java, can you give a more specific example? I have a string "file" storing the filename:                     ByteBuffer buf = new ByteBuffer(4);
buf.order(LITTLE_ENDIAN); what do I do next?

Comment: @SDING, edited to add an example.  You map the file into memory, and then you can read it using the `get*` methods.

Comment: @Mike - you don't _have_ to map it into memory to read it.  you can just use the FileChannel.